# Storm: how to define HDFS URI in HdfsBolt() with a HA HDFS

Tags: hdfs, apache-storm

I'm trying to use `HdfsBolt` to write the output of a Storm topology into a HA enabled HDFS. The topology definition is as follows:

```
// Use pipe as record boundary
RecordFormat format = new DelimitedRecordFormat().withFieldDelimiter("|");
//Synchronize data buffer with the filesystem every 1000 tuples
SyncPolicy syncPolicy = new CountSyncPolicy(1000);
// Rotate data files when they reach five MB
FileRotationPolicy rotationPolicy = new FileSizeRotationPolicy(5.0f, FileSizeRotationPolicy.Units.MB);
// Use default, Storm-generated file names
FileNameFormat fileNameFormat = new DefaultFileNameFormat().withPath("/foo");

HdfsBolt hdfsBolt = new HdfsBolt()
      .withFsUrl("hdfs://devhdfs")
      .withFileNameFormat(fileNameFormat)
      .withRecordFormat(format)
      .withRotationPolicy(rotationPolicy)
      .withSyncPolicy(syncPolicy);
```

The problem is that `HdfsBolt` is not aware of the value of `hdfs://devhdfs` and that triggers a `java.net.UnknownHostException`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: prehdfs
```

I have the original *core-site.xml* where that definition is present, but I don't know how to pass it to `HdfsBolt`. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Storm unable to find the host "devhdfs" in the network. check the host is available or not by pinging, and check hdfsurl will have the port "hdfs://devhdfs:port" and pass the same and try

Comment: I can't give it a single hostname, since it's a HDFS with HA enabled. If I give it a single hostname, it'll work if that hostname is the active NameNode.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that putting `core-site.xml` and `hdfs-site.xml` into `src/main/resources` is the way to go :)

I'm now running into some other issues, but they seem to be HA-related and not Storm-related.